# Regex issuse in javascript and c#

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, validation

I have to build some regex to validate some text. It must work in javascript and c#.
I have to validate text in the following form:

> text 1 text 2 text:2500.50 - valid
>
> text 1:2500.50 - valid
>
> text - valid
>
> text:2500.505 - not valid (only 2 decimals are allowed)
>
> name4: - not valid (if ':' exists then value must be provided)
>
> name - valid

My best shot was:

```
^((([\S \r\t\f]+)\s*:\s*([0-9]+[.][0-9]{2})\s*)|[A-z0-9 \r\t\f\.\$\^\(\|\)\*\+\?\\\’\&\-\,]+\s*)+$
```

Another text i have to validate is:

> 1234 - valid
>
> 1234:3234.577843 - not valid(not valid (only 2 decimals are allowed))
>
> 1234:3234.54 - valid
>
> 1234: - not valid (if ':' exists then value must be provided)
>
> 123456:1234.45 - not valid(first group must have 4 digits).

For this text my best shot was: `^(([0-9]{4})\s*:\s*([0-9]+[.][0-9]{2})\s*|[0-9]{4}\s*)+$`

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: You should explain which cases failed for your regex

Comment: it must work in javascript and c#

Comment: This is a case where my regex failed: 1234:3234.577843 - not valid(not valid (only 2 decimals are allowed)). It thinks that 7843 is another valid group

Comment: Why is this question tagged `R` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex ?

```
^(\d{4}|[\w ]*[A-Za-z][\w ]*)(:\d+(.\d{1,2})?)?$
```

Looks like it's giving the expected result, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MtO0Rd/2).

Comment: This regex is ok but it must validate the entire text. If the text contains one not valid case then the entire text is invalid. 
[This](https://regex101.com/r/n3e8IB/3) a case where the text is valid and [here](https://regex101.com/r/8rqpnu/2) is invalid.
Also i need 2 regex, one for case with text 1 and one for cate with 1234.